# React-Native Undefined is not an object(evaluating this.props.navigator.push')

Tags: react-native

Have a nice day. I'm learning the new React-Native. When I press the input button, I want to start 'StartPage' if the input is successful. But I get the error (evaluating this.props.navigator.push '). Where's the problem?

```
import StartPage from './components/usrFirst';

class LoginForm extends Component {
  onButtonPress() {
    if (.....) {
      this.props.navigator.push({
        component: StartPage
      })
    } else {
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Giriş Yap</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
};
```

Comment: react-navigation? this.props.navigation

Answer (score 0):

defined a stack navigator with routes

[example](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html)

call this function below to push routes

```
this.props.navigation.push('RouteName')
```

Comment: I still have not succeeded, can you explain a little more?

Comment: read this article https://medium.com/@rossbulat/introduction-to-react-navigation-and-navigators-in-react-native-3efcf7239a43